# JQuery source code - absolutely unreadable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it just me or any JavaScript DOM manipulation or WEB UI Framework code is really hard to grasp because of long files, lack of proper indentation and scarcity of comments?

I have read couple good book on JavaScript and like the language, but when trying to understand the inner workings of all the popular frameworks I am having hard time to force myself to go beyond first hundred lines of a huge file.

This is a real question, not a statement. I am just trying to understand if I just suck or somebody else sharing my impressions.

Answer (score 7):

Oh boy. First, stop trying to reverse-engineer minified and obfuscated javaScript. Second, [it's open-source and documented](https://github.com/jquery/jquery).

Comment: @larik Interesting, because I can assure you that the files I linked you to have no scarcity of comments, have proper indentation and have files of objectively-appropriate length. I suppose they aren't meant for the "JavaScript 101" types - you do have to be able to understand how to read *some* code ;)

Comment: @AlienWebguy You are right, the version on GitHub is definitely better structured than the development version that comes with some WEB Stacks. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4):

Who said he is reading minified code?

This question might be closed, but yes, jQuery has some rather unreadable source and bad organization. Organization in that John Resig thought it was a good idea to throw **everything** onto a single constructor and its prototype.

I guess if you want a DOM library that is well commented, try looking at Prototype. It's actually very overcommented in my opinion, but if you want it as a reference for various DOM quirks and mechanics, it might be a good source.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will look at Prototype. Actually I find Ext JS better in this department, but still every JavaScript framework and I am talking about development versions, resides in one huge file.

Comment: In jQuery's defense, the source is multiple files on which the build script is executed: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/src . (Unfortunately, still unreadable in its structure, organization, quality, etc.)

Comment: Unreadable how? That's like saying Wikipedia is useless for people who don't understand English.

Answer (score 3):

The minified version is indeed not human-friendly, but it's smaller and faster. You're looking for the [development version](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js).

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I can understand your frustration, jQuery (and other APIs, C++'s STL springs to mind) are not meant to be read by the average engineer.  They are optimised for their purpose and excel at doing so, and that's why everybody uses them.  Tried and tested.

Comment: I don't think this is strictly true.. take http://paulirish.com/2010/10-things-i-learned-from-the-jquery-source/ for example - a _lot_ can be learnt from reading the jQuery source code (as long as you don't start with the minified version!)

Comment: @Dexter, while I have seen that video and it does rock hard, Paul Irish is NOT the average engineer. He's what we like to call.. a God ;)

Answer (score 0):

Genarally jQuery uses a lot of closures and the notation of the framework as well as the plugins define a lot of anonymus functions on the go. 
So it's not easy "following" the way of the data through the code. At least that is my limited understanding. So if You just suck, You're definetely not the only one.